# Something of Schroedinger Equation bugs me

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, eigenvalue

$\hat{H}\psi(x) = E\psi(x)$

$\psi(x) = c_{1}u_{1}(x) + c_{2}u_{2}(x) + ... = \sum_{n}c_{n}u_{n}(x)$

Here $\psi(x)$ is a superposition state of the eigenfunctions, and $u_{n}(x)$ is eigenfunction, $c_{n}$ is expansion coefficients.

$\int\psi^{*}(x)\hat{H}\psi(x)dx = E\int\psi^{*}(x)\psi(x)dx$

which gives $\sum_{n}c_{n}^{2}E_{n} = E$, which is correct.

However, if I project it into a eigen-level,

$\int u_{m}^{*}(x)\hat{H}\psi(x)dx = E\int u_{m}^{*}(x)\psi(x)dx $

which gives $c_{m}\cdot E_{m} = c_{m}\cdot E$ and this leads to $E_{1} = E_{2} = ...$

It looks like somewhere is not correct, but I am confused...

Comment: When you say “project”, is your intention to rewrite the original state in a different basis, or to collapse the system into a specific new state?

Comment: @CosmasZachos I think OP expanded $\psi$ in a suss preceding equation to get that.

Comment: @CosmasZachos I actually check n=1 and n=2, 2-level system, yes, it leads $c_{1}E_{1} = c_{1}E$

Comment: You can think $\psi(x)$ is a superposition state.

Comment: Proof is correct just not interesting. Given the assumption from the first equation that $\psi$ is an eigenfunction of the Hamiltonian with energy E, then if it can be written as a linear combination of _other eigenfunctions of_ $H$ with unknown energy, then all those eigenfunctions must have the same energy that you assumed $\psi$ has. But make no mistake - this assumption is not general for all wavefunctions $\psi$. I presume your mistake was assuming that $\hat{H}\psi=E\psi$ is an equation that can be written for _any_ $\psi$. When you realize that you see that this proof is not interesting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your very first equation guarantees that *all* states $u_n$ you expand your eigenstate $\psi$ in are degenerate with common eigenvalue $E=E_1=E_2=...$

Otherwise they cannot be part of the expansion. You indeed proved
only $E_1=E_2=...=E$ survive the projection.

$$\int\!\!dx~  u_{m}^{*}(x)\hat{H}\psi(x)\\
=  \int\!\!dx~  u_{m}^{*}(x)\hat{H}  \sum_{n}c_{n}u_{n}(x)\\
 = E_m c_m. $$

Comment: Yes, this one is correct, but the problem is $\int dx u_{m}^{*}(x)E\psi(x) = E c_{m}$...

Comment: I think OP is aware of this. I think the problem is that they implicitly assume, in their calculations, that $\psi$ is also an eigenfunction of $H$... Their calculations then show that $E=E_m$, i.e. that $\psi$ is an eigenfunction with energy $E_m$ (but not that all energies are equal). For other eigenvalues $E_n$, $u_n$ is then orthogonal to $\psi$ and nothing else can be concluded...

Comment: @CosmasZachos UH...OK... I guess I understand What you mean...It cannot simply be projected like this...

Comment: But if it is an eigenstate, as in his first equation, then $E=E_m$, or else  $E=E_n$.... unless they were degenerate....

Comment: @QFT, no, they cannot. Your very first equation guarantees $\psi=u_m$, or $u_k$, .... unless all states you write have the same energy.

Comment: Yes, in the first equation only those $c_n$'s contribute which have the same energies as $\psi$, i.e. only those for which $E_n=E$, indeed.

Comment: But it kind of strange, you have an equation, lhs = rhs, then you find $\int u(x) lhs != \int u(x) rhs$

Comment: OK i see, "Your very first equation guarantees ψ=um
, or uk
, .... unless all states you write have the same energy"  make sense

Comment: You have to modify your question indicating what you assume about the spectrum of H, and why you bother analyzing is eigenstates of eigenvalue E in terms of all eigenstates, instead of just those sharing a unique eigenvalue E....

Comment: @CosmasZachos      OK, so after I did something to make my system into a superposition state of eigenstates, where the superposition state is $\psi(x)$, I cannot claim $\hat{H}\psi = E\psi$, but I can use $\int dx\psi^{*}\hat{H}\psi$ to calculate its energy expectation value?

Comment: Indeed, if you forfeit the powerful, restrictive first eigenvalue equation, then the integral you write calculates the expectation value of the hamiltonian, even for $\psi$ *not* eigenstates of H...

Comment: @CosmasZachos OK I see, I guess I messed up the Schroedinger equation with all other stuff, I thought it is so powerful and ubiquitous and can be used to solve all problems. But here it looks like it is only used to get the eigenvalue and eigenfunction for you...

Answer (score 3):

There seem to be two main possible misconceptions here. First, OP seems to be conflating eigenvalues and expectation values.  Second, OP might be thinking--or at least comptuing as if they think--that every state is an eigenfunction of the Hamiltonian.  Neither of these is true.

---

An eigenfunction $\psi(x)$ of the Hamiltonian satisfies
$$
H\psi(x) = E\psi(x)\,.
$$
Not *every* function $\psi(x)$ is an eigenvector of $H$, but every function *can* be expanded as a linear combination of the eigenvectors of $H$, because they form an orthonormal basis when suitably normalized. Using OP's notation, let's consider an arbitrary state $\psi(x)$ which is not necessarily an eigenstate of $H$.  Then, it can be expanded as
$$
\psi(x) = \sum_nc_nu_n(x)\,,
$$
where
$$
c_n = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}u_n^*(x)\psi(x)dx\,.
$$
In this form, we can show explicitly why this is *not* in general an eigenfunction of $H$ via
$$
H\psi(x) = H \sum_nc_nu_n(x) = \sum_nc_nHu_n(x)
= \sum_nc_nE_nu_n(x)\neq E\sum_nc_nu_n(x)\,,
$$
for some $E$ unless $E_n=E$ for all non-zero $c_n$ in the sum.  Thus, we see that in the very first line of the OP, OP is making an unwarranted assumption.  The rest of the derivation then doesn't follow, and we never get any sort of set of equations that require $E_1=E_2=\cdots\,.$

Thus, not every state has a definite energy. However, we can calculate the *expectation* value of the Hamiltonian to get the predicted average value of the energy after a sequence of measurements on an ensemble of identically prepared systems. This value is
$$
\langle \hat{H} \rangle = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\psi^*(x)H\psi(x)dx\,,
$$
which, after some work, can be shown to be equal to
$$
\langle \hat{H} \rangle = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\psi^*(x)H\psi(x)dx
=\sum_n|a_n|^2E_n
\,,
$$
illustrating exactly why this is considered an *average* value after interpreting the $|a_n|^2$ as probabilities.

Comment: Thanks the problem has been resolved.

Answer (score 2):

The error is that $\psi$ is assumed to be an eigenfunction of $H$, but it is not, unless all $\psi_n$ are degenerate. In the later case $E_n=E$ for ll $n$, indeed.

Comment: Thanks my2cts, the problem has been resolved.